# Injective analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: B(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function such that $f'(0)=1$ and $f'(z) \in B(1,1)$ for all $z \in B(0,1)$. Show that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{re} f'(z) >0$ for all $z \in B(0,1)$.

Suppose $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$ with $z_1 \neq z_2$. Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to B(0,1)$ be given by $\gamma(t) = z_1+t(z_2-z_1)$, then
$f(z_2)-f(z_1) = 0 = \int_0^1 (f \circ \gamma)'(t) dt = \int_0^1 f'(\gamma(t)) (z_2-z_1) dt = \left( \int_0^1 f'(\gamma(t))dt \right) (z_2-z_1)$, from which we get $\int_0^1 f'(\gamma(t))dt = 0$. Taking the real part of both sides yields a contradiction.